# Login function for Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to login into "aminoapps.com" but unable to select login by email..So far I've only managed to get it to open the popup using the login button on the main page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class AminoBot():
    def __init__(self,email,password):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.email = email
        self.password = password


    def signIn(self):
        self.browser.get("https://aminoapps.com/")


        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/div/div/nav/ul/li[3]/a").click()
#        self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("signin-email").click()
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 100)
            self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/button[2]").click()
            emailInput = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/")
            passwordInput = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/form/")
            emailInput.send_keys(self.email)
            passwordInput.send_keys(self.password)
            passwordInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(2)


        finally:
            webdriver.quit()



bot = AminoBot('justlogin@xyz.com','ABCDEFGH')
bot.signIn()
```

So far i've tried the following, to no avail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Sign in with email** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver.get('https://aminoapps.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='nav-link block pointer' and @data-popup='login']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='login-area']//button[@class='auth-btn signin-email']/i[@class='fa fa-envelope']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: amino]